# Closed set and sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, proof-explanation

I understood the closed-sets characterisation Theorem, which states that a set $E \subset X$ is closed in $X$ if and only if for every sequence $x_n$ that belongs to $E$ (for every $n$), we have that $\lim_{n\to +\infty} x_n \in E$.

Correct me if I'm wrong, I am writing "by heart" for what I got, no notes.

So suppose I have to prove the set $[0, 2]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is closed.

- How can I really show that **any** sequence $x_n \in [0, 2]$ for every $n$ natural respects the above condition?

I mean $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ it's ok. $x_n = \frac{3}{2^n}$ does not, for $n = 0$ gives $3$, not in $[0, 2]$.
$x_n = \frac{3}{4^n}$ is ok.

But how can I prove the set is closed "for all" the good sequences?

Comment: It should be "$E$ is closed if and only if for every *convergent* sequence $(x_n) \subseteq E$ with $x_n \rightarrow x$ we have $x \in E$." To that end, show that if $x_n$ is a convergent sequence with $0 \leq x_n \leq 2$ then $0 \leq x \leq 2$.

Comment: @User203940 Oh, I forgot some keyword... Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what your topology is. In the case of $[0,2]$, your example isn't right. The sequence $x_n=\frac{3}{2^n}$ is not a sequence in $[0,2]$ since $x_0\notin[0,2]$. Suppose there is a sequence $x_n\in[0,2]$ such that $lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\notin[0,2]$ so the limit is in the set $(-\infty,0)\cup(2,+\infty)$ which is open, so we can find a neighbourhood of the limit that is not in $[0,2]$ that contains no points of the sequence $x_n$. Since by definition of the limit, every neighbourhood must contain a point of the sequence. We get a contradiction. So every sequence has its limit inside $[0,2]$.

For different topologies your proof might be completely different. It just depends on the topology you are working with.